# Slow response on replica set using mongoid when one node is down

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, mongoid, replicaset

I have a cluster of 3 MongoDB nodes (10.66.5.3, 10.66.5.4, 10.66.5.5) and it all runs smoothly when all nodes are alive and kicking.

Now, when I arbitrarily shut one machine down, I have some high latency (10s) on all db queries when hitting the replica set through the `mongoid` gem. The queries run fine when using the CLI `mongo` tool. The `rs.status()` command returns immediately with the correct information, so I believe the mongoDB side of it is configured properly.

Running the commands from the `pry` console yields the same 10s latency. Occasionally the query will fail when hitting the web api, though I think it's just timeout killing the queries.

Here is the application's mongoid.yml.

```
mock_production:
  sessions:
    default:
      database: project
      hosts:
        - localhost:27017
      options:
        read: :primary
    replica_set:
      database: project
      hosts:
        - 10.66.5.3:27017
        - 10.66.5.4:27017
        - 10.66.5.5:27017
      options:
        read: :primary
        write:
          w: :majority
```

If feels as if the code is checking on the state of the cluster each time and wasting time on the dead node. Am I doing anything wrong, did I miss a configuration option?

I tried adding `refresh_interval: 10` (suggested in a few online resources) to the cluster options but it didn't do anything.

The latency is consistently 10s so I believe there is probably a setting doing something nasty.

Any thoughts?

Software:

- ruby (2.1.5p273)
- rails (4.1.6)
- mongoid (4.0.0)
- moped (2.0.0)

Comment: It sounds like you're hitting a known bug in Moped: https://github.com/mongoid/moped/issues/257. Can you try updating to Moped 2.0.2 or newer and see if that resolves the problem?

Comment: Guillaume ? Is that you ? The  brother of Etienne ?

Comment: @Stennie I should have thought to ask about that at the SydMUG. I updated to mongoid 4.0.1 and moped 2.0.3 and unfortunately still no dice. I'll keep an eye on the issue though. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: @ForgetTheNorm the very same. You might want to hit me on LinkedIn though. SO is hardly the place for fireside chats :)